# Darboux integral mistake in example?

Tags: analysis, riemann-sum

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I856n.png)

Shouldn't the first integral have (b-a) rather than 1 on the end? (i.e the width of the rectangle, the height always being 1). And why is there an inequality sign on the end? Why not just equal?

Thank you!

Comment: $b-a=1$ I think that explains first part.

Comment: Thanks,

Still don't understand why it's 1? surely the width of the rectangle would be (b-a) and the height 1, so the area is 1 times (b-a)?

Comment: It says (a,b) is a subset of [0,1] though? I thought that meant (a,b) could be any interval in between?

Comment: Oops, sorry :). I don't know why we must switch to subintervals. The STANDARD argument may go like that: once you have a step function $\varphi \le$ the Dirichlet function everywhere on $[0,1]$ it must be the zero function on $[0,1].$ Next, if a step function $\varphi$ majorizes the Dirichlet function on $[0,1],$ it must be the constant function taking the value $1.$ In effect, the lower Darboux integral over $[0,1]$ is zero, and the upper Darboux integral over $[0,1]$ is one.

Comment: Both statements on the step functions above use the fact that that any open interval $(a,b)$ does indeed contain a rational point. It seems the author of the textbook simply forgot to replace $a$ with $0$ and $b$ with $1,$ when they obtained the Darboux integrals.